# Run CronJob using GitHub actions

Tags: node.js, github, cron, action

Hello please I'm trying to use GitHub actions to run cron in nodejs that will send birthday reminder to my team.

I have two files, the script running sending the messages and the contacts in csv format.
Here is my workflow file located at .github/workflows/birthday-messages-cron.yml

```
name: Birthday Messages Cron

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/5 * * * *"

jobs:
  send_birthday_messages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
        
      - name: Run birthday message sender
        run: node birthday-message-sender.js
        
      - name: Send email notification
        if: ${{ always() }}
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
        with:
          server_address: smtp.gmail.com
          server_port: 465
          username: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
          to: fidelisepeter@gmail.com
          subject: Birthday Messages Cron Status
          body: |
            Workflow Run: ${{ github.sha }}
            Status: ${{ job.status }}
            Error: ${{ job.steps[3].outcome == 'failure' }}
            
      - name: Set environment variables
        run: |
          echo "BULKSMSNIGERIA_API_KEY=${{ secrets.BULKSMSNIGERIA_API_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Check exit code
        if: ${{ always() }}
        run: exit ${{ job.status == 'success' && steps.send_email.outcome == 'success' ? 0 : 1 }}
```

And here is my birthday-message-sender.js file

```
const axios = require('axios');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

// Function to send SMS
async function sendSMS(name, phoneNumber, message) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://www.bulksmsnigeria.com/api/v1/sms/create', {
      api_token: process.env.BULKSMSNIGERIA_API_KEY,
      from: "RCCG SRP",
      to: phoneNumber,
      body: message,
    });

    if (response.data.status === 'success') {
      console.log(`SMS sent to ${name} at ${phoneNumber} successfully.`);
      return true;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Failed to send SMS to ${name} at ${phoneNumber}. Reason: ${response.data.message}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to send SMS to ${name} at ${phoneNumber}. Error: ${error.message}`);
    return false;
  }
}

// Get current date
const currentDate = new Date();
const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // Month is 0-indexed, so adding 1
const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();

// Read contacts from CSV file
fs.createReadStream('contacts.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', async (data) => {
    // Extract contact details
    const name = data.name;
    const phoneNumber = data.phone_number;
    const birthdate = new Date(data.birthday); // Assuming birthday is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    const birthMonth = birthdate.getMonth() + 1; // Month is 0-indexed, so adding 1
    const birthDay = birthdate.getDate();

    // Check if birthday matches current date
    if (birthMonth === currentMonth && birthDay === currentDay) {
      // Construct birthday message with line breaks
      const message = `Happy birthday, ${name}!\nMay this lovely day bring happiness and new opportunities in your life.\nWishing you the happiest birthday ever!\n\nRCCG - Solid Rock Parish`;

      // Send birthday message
      const result = await sendSMS(name, phoneNumber, message);

      // Log result
      console.log(`SMS send result: ${result}`);
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('Finished sending birthday messages.');
  });
```

Please I don't have much knowledge on GitHub actions or setting the workflow file.

I made the cron

```
schedule:
    - cron: "*/5 * * * *"
```

Is for testing purposes
The cron is expected to run daily
Please I need your assistance.
Thanks